# mongoexport reading a field with a space

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I am trying to export a collection of 'contacts' from MongoDB into a CSV file.  I am using MongoExport.  My document looks as follows:

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": [
   {
        "FirstName": "joe",
        "LastName": "doe" 
   }
]
"address info": [
    {
        "city": "London",
        "postcode": "N1 1AA"
    }
]
}
```

The command I am using is:  `mongoexport --username x --password x --host x --db mydb --collection mycol --type=csv --fields name.FirstName,name.LastName,Address Info.city,Address Info.postcode --out "c:\myfile.csv"`

The issue I am having is getting the fields for "address info".  I tried wrapping "address info" with {} and also adding an underscore like address_info but it didn't work.  I keep getting the error:  "too many positional arugments...".  Any sugesstions?

Also, how can i force the command to overwrite the csv file it exists on disk already?

Comment: Try a backslash before the space ```\```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the field name with a quote. Like `--fields name.FirstName,name.LastName,'Address Info.city',Address Info.postcode`

Comment: @koen, do you mean like this?  `address\info.city`?  If so, it didn't work.

Comment: @alex, wrapping the field in a quote like `'address info.city'` throws the error "too many positional arguments"

Comment: No, before the space `address\ info.city`

Comment: @Koen, that didn't work either.  Getting the "too many positional arguments" error message

Comment: According to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/279121/14113) you have to use `^` on windows, instead of ```\``` (which is the default for unix). So try `address^ info.city`

Comment: Or if that doesn't work, try to wrap the fields as a whole: `--fields "name.FirstName,name.LastName,Address Info.city,Address Info.postcode"`

Comment: @Koen, I tried both and neither worked.  Thanks for the help thus far, any other suggestions?

Comment: @Koen, your suggestion to wrap the fields as a whole as  `--fields "name.Firstname,name.LastName,Address Info.city,Address Info.postcode"`worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. Solved it by Wrapping the field using double quotes.
Ex Using double quotes as follows " Address Info " in windows mongo 3.2.3 works.

Comment: Worked for me too, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344949/mongoexport-reading-a-field-with-a-space#comment60484870_36344949